# Angular extract all header files html in one file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I looking how i can put all the headers(scripts, css) of the different html in one file for structure the code. I see that maybe grunt works but i not sure.

Comment: Are you looking for a minify tool like https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your question, but if you want all your pages to share the same header/footer, just use **angular routing with ng-view**.

```
<html>
<!-- ... -->
<body>
<!-- here your header -->
<ng-view />
<!-- here your footer -->
<!-- here your scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

`ng-view` will inject the appropriate template depending of the route choosed.

Take a look at : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Thank you i will look. what i want is all the pages loads all the scripts in one (share).